# Use Camera2 to Preview and Process camera data

Tags: android, android-camera2

## Question

I want to do something similar to what's done on the [Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) sample, that is:

1. **Previewing** images from the camera using a `TextureView`
2. **Processing** images from the camera using a `ImageReader`

With a few differences regarding `2`:

- I'm only interested on the gray channel (brightness) from the images to be processed. Their dimensions should be around 1000 x 1000 pixels (and not the highest resolution available)
- When a image to be processed is available, a generic `process(Image)` method will be called instead of saving images to disk. What this method does is out of the scope of this question, but it takes around 50 ms to return
- The image data should be processed periodically (around 10 FPS, but speed is not critical) instead of eventually

How can I accomplish this using the `Camera2` API?

## Observations

- I've changed the way I'm creating the `ImageReader` instance, selecting smaller dimensions and a different format (`YUV_420_888` instead of `JPEG`). The `Y` plane will be accessed in order to get the brightness data. Is there a more efficient format (since I'm simply ignoring the `U` and `V` planes)?
- Both `TextureView` and `ImageReader` surfaces should be filled periodically, but at different rates. Since there can be only one repeating `CameraRequest` on a `CameraCaptureSession` (which can be set by calling `setRepeatingRequest()`), am I supposed to manually call `capture()` periodically (e.g. call `setRepeatingRequest()` with the preview request and call `capture()` periodically with the process request)?
- Can the performance be improved by sending reprocessed requests to obtain the images to be processed from the preview images? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to help you with the gray channel, I suggest you to try to study the planes of the YUV format image and try to get it from there.

Also try to check all the values that you can set in the CaptureBuilder, maybe you can achieve your objetive using SENSOR_TEST_PATTERN_MODE, COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE, or BLACK_LEVEL_LOCK. You can check all the info in [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html)

About process just one of every 10 frames, just discard the frames in your process() method using a simple:

```
   if (result.getFrameNumber() % 10 != 0) return;
```

Finally remember to close all the images that you recieve in your ImageReader OnImageAvailableListener to avoid memory leaks and improve your performance :P

```
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
        Image image = null;
        try {
            image = imageReader.acquireNextImage();
            //Do whatever you want with your Image
            if (image != null) {
                image.close();
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException iae) {
            if (image != null) {
                image.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

hope that it will help you, let me know if I can help you in something else!